# Stringing nuts together: a question on the Bartenura, Uqtzin 2:5

Tags: hebrew, mishna, bartenura, maseches-uktzin

In explaining the Mishna, the Bartenura often clarifies obscure words by providing a cognate word in either Hebrew or Aramaic - the latter usually taken from the Targum, but sometimes from the Bavli or Yerushalmi. In Uqtzin 2:5, he explains the verb, אמנן (as in, האגוזים שאמנן) to mean "braided, joined together" (שגדלן וחברן זו לזו), and then backs that up with a verse in Esther: "ויהי אומן את הדסה" (Esther 2:7).

Since Mordekhai was neither braiding Esther nor joining her to something else, how does this passuk clarify the meaning of the word in its mishnaic context??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's why he says "שגדלן" (which otherwise seems out of place when talking about stringing things together. I mean, yeah, by doing so you're making something that's bigger, but that's not usually thought of as embiggening the nuts): to show the connection to the word in Esther which means "to embiggen" in another sense, viz to rear.

Just my own thought: I've no support for it.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I read that as "braid them"...

Comment: @ShimonbM, the usual root for "braid" I think is "קלע".

Comment: Not always - see Bartenura on Kiddushin 2:3. The word קלע turns up a bunch of times in the Mishna, but mostly as a noun (eg: לפני הקלעים, throughout Zevachim).

Answer (score 1):

פרק ב - משנה ה

חִבּוּר. הִתְחִיל לְפָרֵק, אֹכֶל שֶׁהִתְחִיל בּוֹ, אֵינוֹ חִבּוּר. ‎**‏ הָאֱגוֹזִים שֶׁאֲמָנָן‏ ‎**‏ הָאֱגוֹזִים וְהַשְּׁקֵדִים, חִבּוּר, עַד שֶׁיְּרַסֵּס:‏
 
 ר"ע מברטנורה  הַמְחַתֵּךְ לְבַשֵּׁל. ...:

**הָאֱגוֹזִים שֶׁאֲמָנָן** 


*שֶׁגִּדְּלָן*

 וְחִבְּרָן זוֹ בָזוֹ. לְשׁוֹן וַיְהִי אֹמֵן אֶת הֲדַסָּה (אֶסְתֵּר ב):  ... ‏
‏
Omen= growing. See Tif'eret Israel [51](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37951&st=&pgnum=462)
See Mishna Kiddushin Shifcha Gadelet (chapter 2 mishna 3 "עַל מְנָת שֶׁיֶּשׁ לִי בַת אוֹ שִׁפְחָה גַדֶּלֶת" (Bartenura "קוֹלַעַת שְׂעַר הַנָּשִׁים ")). Gadel = Braiding

### Your question is Strong

But the point is the translation between the radical "גדל" and the radical "אמן", after this, the figurative sense and others are contingents.
Gadel = Braiding; Aman = Gadel; => Aman = Braiding;
To grow, a crop, for example, some things can not grown if you do not make a Braid. garlic braids are length. Curly hear without Braids seem least length.

Comment: @Shimon bM I hope that this makes sense

Comment: It makes sense, I just think it's a weak connection. Normally, the Bartenura cites supporting verses that use the word in a straightforward sense. This one seems more like a drosh...

Comment: @ShimonbM Shifcha gadelet is not a drush. the similarities between grown and cultivate too.

Comment: @ShimonbM may be following Bartenura Shabbat 10, 6 [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37941&st=&pgnum=161) make thicker.

Comment: @ShimonbM Rashi on Chumash Shemot 28, 22